# Presentation of a many-to-many relation in web page

Tags: html, database, user-interface, many-to-many

Building a library database administration, it has a many-to-many relation (books, writers) and i wonder how to present to the user the management interface.

When editing a book, one must choose writer(s). But how? From a multiple choice drop-down-list? - It would be huge. From a number of drop-down-lists? - hard to control their number and present them in a dedicated module in the page. (Actually the later seems to me a doable solution.)

Any other suggestions? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the same way StackOverflow uses to enable you tag multiple technologies while posting a question

It enables you to write the tag manually, and helps you with smart auto complete.

I see this way avoids huge drop down lost and simplifies controlling

Comment: Thanks. After my first research, i think AJAX comes in my way, right?

Comment: You have 2 options:
- **AJAX calls** , if your are going to load writers data o demand.
- **Caching**, where you load all writers in a JSON to the client.
Select the approach that fits your data size and nature and system usage as well